# How to convert decimal to binary in 64 bits?

Tags: c, binary, decimal, data-conversion

so I have this code

```
int main()
{
  int n, c, k;

  printf("Enter an integer\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("%d in binary is:\n", n);

  for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
  {
    k = n >> c;

    if (k & 1)
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}
```

It converts decimal into binary but only in 32 bits. When I change it into 64 bits it doesn't work (it seems like it just doubles the result from 32 bits). At the same time it works fine with 8 or 4 bits etc. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you converting to 64-bits? `c = 63`?

Comment: @AntonH: Unless `int` is 64 bits, that invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: use `<stdint.h>` and fixed size types.

Comment: Using a signed integer for bitshifts is a bad idea, as it it implementation defined **at best** (certain shifts invoke undefined behaviour). Use an unsigned integer. Also `int` is not guarateed to have 32 bits. If you need  a specific width, use fixed-width types from `stdint.h`.

Comment: @Olaf I asked because OP hasn't specified what they've done to convert to 64-bits. Asked to mainly get clarification for that.

Comment: @AntonH yes, that's how I was converting it by c = 63.

Comment: Check `sizeof int`.   A typical value is `4`, which corresponds to a 32-bit type.   Trying to fiddle 64 bits of a 32-bit quantity, as you are, gives undefined behaviour.   If you want 64-bits, use `long long unsigned`.   Bear in mind that `int` can feasibly be only 16-bit (which would make the 32-bit version of your code also give undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

> *It converts decimal into binary but only in 32 bits. When I change it into 64 bits it doesn't work (it seems like it just doubles the result from 32 bits).*

The problem is here.

```
  int n, c, k;

  printf("Enter an integer\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
```

`n` is an `int` which can be as small as 16 bits. It could be 64 bits, but it's probably 32 bits. When you try to enter a 64 bit number you'll get garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    printf("sizeof(int) == %zu\n", sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("n = %d\n", n);
}

$ ./test
sizeof(int) == 4
Enter an integer
12345678901
n = -539222987
```

Instead, you can use a `long long int` which has a minimum size of 64 bits or `int64_t` from [`stdint.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h) which is exactly 64 bits. I have a preference for using the explicit width types in code that requires a specific width to make it more obvious to the reader.

`long long int` uses `%lld` for `scanf` and `printf` while `int64_t` uses [macros from inttypes.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Printf_and_scanf_format_specifiers). The code below takes advantage of C automatically concatenating constant strings; `"foo" "bar"` and `"foobar"` are equivalent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    int64_t n;

    printf("Enter an integer\n");

    scanf("%"SCNd64, &n);

    printf("n = %"PRId64"\n", n);
}


$ ./test
Enter an integer
12345678901
n = 12345678901
```

Comment: `%lld` is not necessarily the correct conversion type specifier for the fixed width types. Use the macros from `inttypes.h`. Btw. some implementations have built-in types for the fixed width type-names (`stdint.h` just `typedefs` the standard names to these built-in names), thus they are clearly distinct from the standard types.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks! I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your n & k variables' data type. They are integer. Check your platform's data type size using sizeof(int).

When you change to 64-bits, these variables can't hold 64-bit values.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

the following code is one way to handle the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    long long unsigned int n;
    long long          int c;
    long long unsigned int k;

    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%llu", &n) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for 64 bit number failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    printf("%llu in binary is:\n", n);

    for (c = 63; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        k = n >> c;

        if (k & 1)
            putc('1', stdout);
        else
            putc('0', stdout);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

and here is the output from a typical run of the program:

```
Enter an integer
6789097860397846  
6789097860397846 in binary is:
0000000000011000000111101010011000000110010100000111101100010110
```

Comment: Note: the above was run on ubuntu linux 16.04 with gcc used to compile and link.